# Is it possible to pass a value from child route to its parent route with react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's say, I have a MainLayout with a header and a body. With react router, I render the component in the body.

```
...
<header></header>
<main>{this.props.children}</main>
...
```

This is my current router :

```
<Route component={MainLayout} onEnter={requireCordova}>
   <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
   <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
</Route>
```

My question is I want MainLayout to grab the title from one of its child  (to fill the header), is it possible?

```
<Route component={MainLayout} onEnter={requireCordova}>
   <Route path="/home" component={Home} title='homepage' />
   <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} title='settings'  />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not communicate between components directly. You may want to use a shared store for such requirements - the most popular solution being [Redux](http://redux.js.org).

To address your specific problem of updating the title - there is a simple utility [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) that simplifies the process.

You can simply use the Helmet component inside any of your route components: 
`<Helmet title="My Title" />` and helmet will take care of updating your title. It works for other elements that go in HTML head as well - eg. meta, link, script tags etc.